# Sass-loader with Webpack, React and Babel not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, sass-loader

I apologize for a code-heavy post.

I'm both new to Node, React and Webpack and a first-time sass-loader user. I'm running into some problems which seem to be trivial, but aren't.

> ERROR in ./app/index.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'waterbottle.scss' in '/Volumes/500GB/Webs/waterbottle/app'  @
>   ./app/index.js 4:13-40

I've tried placing the .scss file in the app folder, as well as fiddling with the .scss path.

**Installation:**

I installed sass-loader with

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev
```

**webpack.config.js** looks like this

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HTMLWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
    template: __dirname + '/app/index.html',
    filename: 'index.html',
    inject: 'body'
});

module.exports = {
    entry: __dirname + '/app/index.js',
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ],
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: 'app.build.js'
    },
    plugins: [HTMLWebpackPluginConfig],
    stats: {
        colors: true
    },
    devtool: 'source-map',
    watch: true
};
```

**package.json** includes this in devDependencies

```
"node-sass": "^4.5.3",
```

**index.js** contains

```
const scss = require("waterbottle.scss");
```

File structure:

[image]

My understanding is that sass-loader should automatically inject css into the dom. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solved. I needed to install:

```
npm install style-loader --save
npm install css-loader --save
```

And path to .scss file:

```
const scss = require("../scss/waterbottle.scss");
```

I'm very curious why this is not mentioned on [sass-loader website](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader), or better yet, installed automatically when running

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass webpack --save-dev
```

Comment: I did the same and imported the scss file in my component but not working

Answer (score 2):

[Sass loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader) documentation shows it like:

```
// webpack.config.js

module.exports = {
    ...
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [{
                loader: "style-loader" // creates style nodes from JS strings
            }, {
                loader: "css-loader" // translates CSS into CommonJS
            }, {
                loader: "sass-loader" // compiles Sass to CSS
            }]
        }]
    }
};
```